# Disabled ec2-user ssh access by mistake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, openssh

I have disabled ec2-user ssh access by removing authorization key and turn on public key authentication by mistake. Now I unable to access the server.

Is there any way to gain access back?

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to recover the ssh access to your instance in certain cases. The exact steps are described in [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair) of the AWS docs.

Warning:

> Do not perform this procedure if your instance is a store-backed
>   instance, because this recovery procedure requires a stop and start of
>   your instance, and any data will be lost. For more information, see
>   [Determining the Root Device Type of Your Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#display-instance-root-device-type).